# Can the topology of a quad mesh with irregular vertices be represented as a square grid graph?

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, computational-geometry

I would like to know whether the topology of a quad mesh containing irregular vertices (vertices of degree higher or lower than 4) can be represented as a square grid graph or not.

Ideally I would like to find (or build) an algorithm that takes a quad mesh in input and computes its topological representation as a 2D array.

For clarity I have made this example where I tried to depict the adjacency relations between the faces of a quad mesh with irregular vertices inside a regular 2D grid.

[image]

Provided this representation is correct:

- Do you think it can be generalized to other quad meshes with irregular vertices ?
- If so, would there be a name for it ?
- If so, would there be an algorithm to compute it ? (related to graph theory maybe ?)

*note: this question was first asked on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62944526/can-the-topology-of-a-quad-mesh-with-irregular-vertices-be-represented-as-a-squa) but I was suggested to post/move it here as Math SE seems to be more appropriate for this kind of topic.*

Answer (score 1):

Of course, this *can* only work if the mesh is homeomorphic to a plane (and not, say, to a torus or a monkey head) to begin with.

But otherwise, this seems to follow by induction as in the following sketch: Remove one quad with with at least one boundary edge, build a square grid for the rest; add squares representing the removed quad to the correct neighbours and perhaps "extrude" a few boundary squares to make the grid rectangular again.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your answer, does your routine works with "stars" (vertices of valence 5). Would you mind to provide a simple example ?

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more in detail?